# Android spinner implementation not showing selected item

Tags: android, spinner

I have 3 Spinners and I am selecting values from each of them. But when I declare the setOnItemSelected() method outside of the onClickListener() of the next button, The selected value doesn't show up in the Toast. When I declare the setOnItemSelected() method inside the onClickListener of the button, it works but then I can't hide my edittext when I select "Set Limit" from the last spinner.
Please help.
Below is my .java file.

```
public class AvailabilityActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private Button next;
private Spinner advanceNotice, shortestTrip, longestDist;
private Bundle bundle;
private EditText setLimit;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_availability);

    bundle = getIntent().getExtras();
    intializeSpinners();
    setLimit = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.setlimit);
    ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapteradvNotice = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this, R.array.advNoticeArray, R.layout.spinner_layout);
    adapteradvNotice.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);

    advanceNotice.setAdapter(adapteradvNotice);

    ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adaptershortestTrip = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this, R.array.shortestTripArray, R.layout.spinner_layout);
    adaptershortestTrip.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);

    shortestTrip.setAdapter(adaptershortestTrip);

    ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapterlongestDist = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this, R.array.longestDistanceArray, R.layout.spinner_layout);
    adapterlongestDist.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);

    longestDist.setAdapter(adapterlongestDist);
    onNextPressed();
}

private void intializeSpinners() {
    advanceNotice = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.acceptAdvanceNotice);
    shortestTrip = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.acceptShortestTrip);
    longestDist = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.acceptLongestTrip);
}

private void onNextPressed() {
    next = (Button) findViewById(R.id.nextButton1);

    final String[] setLimitText = {""};
    final String[] selectedlongestDist = new String[1];
    longestDist.setOnItemSelectedListener(new Spinner.OnItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            selectedlongestDist[0] = parent.getItemAtPosition(position).toString();
            if (selectedlongestDist[0].equals("Set Limit")){
                setLimit.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                setLimitText[0] = setLimit.getText().toString();
            }
            if (selectedlongestDist[0].equals("No Limit")) {
                setLimit.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

        }
    });

    if (setLimitText[0] == "")
        setLimitText[0] = selectedlongestDist[0];


    next.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            final String[] selectedNotice = new String[1];
            advanceNotice.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
                @Override
                public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                    selectedNotice[0] = parent.getItemAtPosition(position).toString();
                }

                @Override
                public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

                }
            });

            final String[] selectedshortestTrip = new String[1];
            shortestTrip.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
                @Override
                public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                    selectedshortestTrip[0] = parent.getItemAtPosition(position).toString();
                }

                @Override
                public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

                }
            });

            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), setLimitText[0], Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            bundle.putString("advancenotice", selectedNotice[0]);
            bundle.putString("shortesttrip", selectedshortestTrip[0]);
            bundle.putString("longesttrip", setLimitText[0]);

            Intent intent = new Intent(getBaseContext(),ImageActivity.class);
            intent.putExtras(bundle);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
}
}
```

Below is my layout file.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="com.example.csci567.dailyrentals.AvailabilityActivity">


<TextView
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="How much advance notice do you need to confirm a trip request?"
    android:textColor="#000000"
    android:textSize="18dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
    android:id="@+id/advanceNoticeRequestText"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.035"
    android:layout_marginStart="15dp" />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Advance notice"
    android:textSize="14dp"
    android:id="@+id/advanceNoticeText"
    android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.13"
    android:layout_marginStart="15dp" />

<Spinner
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/acceptAdvanceNotice"
    android:hint="Advance Notice"
    style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Spinner.Underlined"
    android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.18"
    android:layout_marginStart="15dp" />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Block trips that don't give you enough advance notice."
    android:textSize="16dp"
    android:id="@+id/blockNoticeText"
    android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.26"
    android:layout_marginStart="15dp" />

<View android:background="#a8a8a6"
    android:layout_width = "0dp"
    android:layout_height="1dp"
    android:id="@+id/separatorLine1"
    android:layout_marginTop="25dp"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.3"/>

<TextView
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="How long would you like trips to last?"
    android:textSize="18dp"
    android:textColor="#000000"
    android:id="@+id/tripDurationText"
    android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.4"
    android:layout_marginStart="15dp" />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Shortest possible trip"
    android:textSize="14dp"
    android:id="@+id/shortestTripText"
    android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.46"
    android:layout_marginStart="15dp" />

<Spinner
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/acceptShortestTrip"
    android:hint="Enter Shortest Trip"
    style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Spinner.Underlined"
    android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.52"
    android:layout_marginStart="15dp" />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Longest Possible trip"
    android:textSize="14dp"
    android:id="@+id/longestTripText"
    android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.6"
    android:layout_marginStart="15dp" />

<Spinner
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/acceptLongestTrip"
    android:hint="Enter Longest Trip"
    style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Spinner.Underlined"
    android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.66"
    android:layout_marginStart="15dp" />

<EditText
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/setlimit"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.76"
    android:hint="Enter the value of longest possible trip"
    android:layout_marginStart="15dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="15dp" />

<Button
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="35dp"
    android:text="Next"
    android:textSize="18dp"
    android:textColor="#ffffff"
    android:background="#8b36bc"
    android:id="@+id/nextButton1"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="1.0"/>

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

The way you're coding is the problem.

First thing you must change is the place you set listeners. You should avoid setting listeners inside other listeners.

Secondly, the code will execute all the code out of those listeners and then execute the code inside those listeners.

Thirdly, if you wanna show a `Toast` with a message generated inside a `Spinner`, you should put it inside the spinner's listener.

Try to reorganize you code thinking of those tips and see if you'll have the problem again.

Comment: Ok. will try to rearrange it. Thanks for the reply

Comment: I tried putting all the setOnItemSelectListener() outside the onClickListener() and everything else works fine. But as you can see in my code, I need to put that value in the bundle and pass on to next activity. Now I cant put bundle inside setOnItemSelectListener() as everytime user selects a value, it will be entered into the bundle. And I can't access the selected value inside the onClickListener() of the button.

Comment: @ParagAgrawal you can do many thing according to your business rule. You can store the data from `setOnItemSelectListener()` in a variable and get this data when you'll call the activity, and at this time, you can pass the data to the bundle, or even use the bundle itself. You can put the data into bundle directly from the `setOnItemSelectListener()` and make a check to avoid duplicate values. I got a question, why are you using `String[]` if you only use the first position of the array?

Comment: I am using string array because the android studio was giving error when I used only string and provided only this as a acceptable solution when press alt+enter. Its not letting me use a single variable inside the listener.

Comment: It doesn't make sense. Maybe you was declaring them incorrectly.

Comment: Well I had to do some more patching of code but now its working. Thanks a lot for all your help.